# Extending JavaFX ListView Control

Tags: listview, javafx, controls, extend

I would like to make a control very simple to ListView, but when I try to copy all the things related to ListView and renaming them my own, to change some functionality later, I come upon some variables/calls to some functions, that come from the javafx.control package which are protected. Any help would be really awesome. Thanks

Comment: Why are you copying the code? Can't you just subclass it (or otherwise customize it)? What are you trying to change?

Comment: I would like to make a list view, where you can set the number of items, disable scroll bar, add buttons to each side of listview which takes you to either side of the listview. And then to have images or some other controls in the listview.